# Manipulating Qt resources by URL at runtime

Tags: qt, qml

I use Qt resources in my QML application. I want to change the resource used by some items at run-time.

In the following example, the `Image` object uses a resource. It is correctly displayed. If I click on it, the handler sets what appears to be the same value, but it does not work : the `Image` object can't load the resource.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("qrc file not updating")

    Image
    {
        id: gfx
        source: "qrc:/../../../../Qt/5.9/Src/qtquickcontrols2/examples/quickcontrols2/chattutorial/shared/Ernest Hemingway@2x.png"
        width: 200
        height: 200
    }
    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: gfx
        onPressed: gfx.source = "qrc:/../../../../Qt/5.9/Src/qtquickcontrols2/examples/quickcontrols2/chattutorial/shared/Ernest Hemingway@2x.png"
    }
}
```

Changing `qrc` to `file` to use a file instead of a resource works.

Is it possible to change a used resource at run-time (instanciating another QML object - here, an `Image` - works, but I need to use the same object).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the notify signal?

```
onPressed: {
    gfx.source = "qrc://my/new/image.png";
    gfx.sourceChanged();
}
```

https://forum.qt.io/topic/6935/how-to-reload-an-image-in-qml/18

Also qrc implies it is found in a qt resource file included in your .pro file.  So if it works with a `file://` then you may need to add the second one into your qresource file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you suggest. Isn't the sourceChanged a signal emitted by the Image instance that you can connect to, for instance using the qml onSourceChanged: property ? I've tried nonetheless, and got an error.